# Why does "prop('checked')" return undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="my_chk" id="my_chk" value="1">
```

I'm trying to check whether or not it's checked:

```
$("#my_chk").prop('checked')
```

It returns undefined. Why?

When I'm trying ".is('checked')" it returns false always, even when it's checked.

Comment: check if id is duplicating or not, if yes, then it is considering first element inside dom

Comment: @RahulMeshram, unique

Comment: Then it should work : [check](https://jsfiddle.net/67rLfa00/). check errors in console if any. and as of now, your checkbox is not checked

Comment: Check for errors in the console. Your code works fine. Also note that `is(':checked')` will return `false` in all occasions when the `checked` property is anything other than `true`, hence why you see `false`

Comment: Works fine, see: https://jsfiddle.net/h8zkq2c8/

Comment: @RahulMeshram, it doesn't work -- the value is 1 but it returns false in your example

Comment: but it should be checked right, what you exactly want, checked input's value? or checked or not? I am confused now

Comment: Your code above returns false? What browser do you use to get undefined?

Comment: Once check for answer for all your expectations.

Comment: @Quma, the `value` is what gets posted to the server when the form is submitted (assuming the checkbox is checked), but the `value` has no relation to what `.prop('checked')` or `.is(':checked')` will return - those will *always* produce either `true` or `false`.

Comment: @PeterB how can I determine on a client whether it's checked or not? now it always return false

Comment: @Quma if you do it correctly - as in the example I edited in to your question - it works fine. There must be an error elsewhere in the code that you haven't shown us

Answer (score 1):

To check if a checkbox is checked use

`$("#my_chk").is(':checked')`

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#my_chk').on('change',function(){
  console.log($("#my_chk").prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_chk" id="my_chk" value="1">
```

It's work well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example of both you want, whether checked or not and checked's value

```js
$("#my_chk").change(function() {
  console.log($("#my_chk").prop('checked'))
  if ($("#my_chk").prop('checked')) {
    alert('checkbox value : ' + $("#my_chk:checked").val());
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="my_chk" id="my_chk" value="1">
```